# Subsubsection floating

Tags: floats, subsection

The images below and the code show how 50° subsubsection is not where I placed it. Any solution?

[image: 50° is below the first image]

[image]

```
\section{Experimental results}
      In this section the temperature vs time plots are shown and commented as well as the 
        bidimensional thermal wave developed by the heat flux flux provided. It is reminded 
           that every experiment lasts for 300 s (5 min).
         \subsection{Unidirection carbon fiber plate}
       \subsubsection{\SI{40}{\celsius}}
       \begin{figure} [h!]
            \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Immagini/PLQ 200-01-399 40° C/50x}
            \caption{Temperature vs time (s) of the measurement point placed at 50mm from the 
           center of the plate along the x axis.}
            \end{figure}
             \begin{figure} [h!]
              \centering
              \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Immagini/PLQ 200-01-399 40° C/78x}
                \caption{Temperature vs time (s) of the measurement point placed at 78mm from 
      the center of the plate along the x axis.}
     \end{figure}
        \begin{figure} [h!]
          \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Immagini/PLQ 200-01-399 40° C/107x}
                  \caption{Temperature vs time (s) of the measurement point placed at 107mm 
           from the center of the plate along the x axis.}
           \end{figure}
             \begin{figure} [h!]
            \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Immagini/PLQ 200-01-399 40° C/30y}
           \caption{Temperature vs time (s) of the measurement point placed at 30mm from the 
        center of the plate along the y axis.}
            \end{figure}
         \begin{figure} [h!]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.75]{Immagini/PLQ 200-01-399 40° C/export/queste/init}
            \caption{Thermal wave at t=5 s.}
          \end{figure}
          \begin{figure} [h!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.75]{Immagini/PLQ 200-01-399 40° C/export/queste/meta}
           \caption{Thermal wave at t=150 s.}
          \end{figure}
            \begin{figure} [h!]
              \centering
               \includegraphics[scale=0.75]{Immagini/PLQ 200-01-399 40° C/export/queste/fine}
             \caption{Thermal wave at t=300 s.}
             \end{figure}
               \subsubsection{\SI{50}{\celsius}}
             \begin{figure} [h!]
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Immagini/PLQ 200-01-399 50° C/50x}
                 \caption{Temperature vs time (s) of the measurement point placed at 50mm from 
             the center of the plate along the x axis.}
            \end{figure}
            \begin{figure} [h!]
          \centering
             \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Immagini/PLQ 200-01-399 50° C/78x}
              \caption{Temperature vs time (s) of the measurement point placed at 78mm from 
       the center of the plate along the x axis.}
        \end{figure}
       \begin{figure} [h!]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Immagini/PLQ 200-01-399 50° C/107x}
            \caption{Temperature vs time (s) of the measurement point placed at 107mm from the 
            center of the plate along the x axis.}
            \end{figure}
            \begin{figure} [h!]
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Immagini/PLQ 200-01-399 50° C/30y}
                   \caption{Temperature vs time (s) of the measurement point placed at 30mm 
                     from the center of the plate along the y axis.}
                 \end{figure}
                \begin{figure} [h!]
            \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=0.75]{Immagini/PLQ 200-01-399 50° C/export/queste/init}
            \caption{Thermal wave at t=5 s.}
                     \end{figure}
                         \begin{figure} [h!]
                            \centering
                        \includegraphics[scale=0.75]{Immagini/PLQ 200-01-399 50° 
                          C/export/queste/meta}
                           \caption{Thermal wave at t=150 s.}
                            \end{figure}
                       \begin{figure} [h!]
                            \centering
                        \includegraphics[scale=0.75]{Immagini/PLQ 200-01-399 50° 
                          C/export/queste/fine}
                                     \caption{Thermal wave at t=300 s.}
                             \end{figure}
```

Comment: your question is not very clear, section headings never float, however `figure` float (that is the only function of the `figure` environment) as you have used `[h]` (which usually generates a warning), you are specifying that the figure may not be placed at the top or bottom of a page or on a page just containing figures, this makes it very hard to place the figure anywhere

Comment: I meant why my subsubsection 50° is right after the first figure if I wanted it to be after several ones as shown in the code

Comment: Thank you. I placed a \FloatBarrier before my subsubsection and it works.

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks mate